# Error "Define and run multi-container applications with Docker" when running docker-compose cmd

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When running the following command `docker-compose -f ./docker-compose-frontend.yml --env-file .env up` I get the following error "Define and run multi-container applications with Docker" which provides no further guidance.

Installed on the system is Docker 20.10.7 and docker-compose 1.18.0.

yml files specify version number 3.3 which should be suitable with this version of compose so I'm not really sure what the issue is.

Any suggestions on things to try would be great as I am now just scratching my head on this one.

Answer (score 0):

use `sudo apt install docker-compose-plugin -y` then try to install again